# eps files render badly

Tags: linux, debian, ghostscript, postscript, eps

When I open or convert eps files created with gnuplot, some of the lines don't come out properly.  I am using Debian squeeze. Strangely when I view them on a windows PC they look fine.

See attatched example[image]

This was converted with the command:

gs -r400 -dEPSCrop -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile=output.png -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE input.eps

the results are the same when viewed on the screen. Notice on the aerofoil lower surface, some of the line segments are actually triangles.

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `gs -v` for you?

Comment: Also, without access to your input.eps it may proof to become impossible to tell why you see the triangles... (So this plot is showing an airfoil profile ?!?)

Comment: **How** do you view the EPS on a Windows PC? What EPS viewer do you use there?